# FileMaker XML Web Publishing

Tags: filemaker

We currently have a FileMaker Server instanace running, it already has PHP web publishing running.

I'm just wondering is it as simple as ticking enable XML web publishing for it to be up and running or have I got to restart the server??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable it in the server deployment, then you need at least 1 user account in the file with the extended privilege to grant access via php/xml/iwp etc. You will need a user account in EACH file you want to have access to with the appropriate extended privilege.

Then comes the fun of actually working with the FMXML or FMPHP engine hehe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Do you know if you have to restart the server once enableing it on the server?